# CSS first child of specific class

Tags: css

I have the following piece of HTML code:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
<span class="route-line">4</span>
<span class="route-line">33</span>
```

I would like to add some style on the **first** `span` with `class="route-line"`. Is it possible with CSS? It is something like `nth-of-type`; if it had existed, it would have been called `nth-of-type-with-class`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First span with class **.route-line** followed for any other element that don't have class **.route-line**

```
*:not(.route-line) + span.route-line
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: You can replace * with a span if you notice any slowness

Comment: That's right. It's similar to the previous accepted answer, but I believe this one is closer to what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In such cases you can use the sibling selector. Like so:

```
.ui-icon + .route-line{
    color: red;
}
```

It will style only the `span` which follows the element with a class `ui-icon`.

Comment: I will probably stick with this solution until I find a better one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you apply another class to the element you want to style.

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
<span class="route-line custom-route-line">4</span>
<span class="route-line">33</span>
```

And the css would look like this

```
.custom-route-line{/*your styling goes here*/}
```

Note both styles of classes (route-line & custom-route-line) will apply to that element.
[Take a look here](http://jsfiddle.net/QZ5jE/)

Comment: I know, but I wanted to keep the HTML as clean as possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you were looking for is `span.route-line:first-of-type`, but it's poorly supported.